# OpenCV Alphabets detection and extraction on shape of alphabet after skeletonization

Tags: c++, tesseract, opencv3.0

I want to detect and extract  alphabets from  image and create new image only contains alphabets.I have applied skeletonization on the image after that I want some suggestions.How can we detect letters using contours or stroke bases.The images I am using are basically dvd player pack panel e.g,

[image: DVD back panel]

The code I am using for skeletonization is

```
cvtColor(input, input, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(input, input, 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::Mat skel(input.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
cv::Mat temp;
cv::Mat eroded;

cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3));

bool done;
do
{
    cv::erode(input, eroded, element);
    cv::dilate(eroded, temp, element); // temp = open(input)
    cv::subtract(input, temp, temp);
    cv::bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
    eroded.copyTo(input);

    done = (cv::countNonZero(input) == 0);
} while (!done);
```

The output Image After skeletonization,

[image: Image After Skeletonization]

Source :http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/

Comment: In OpenCV 3.0 there is an extra module for text detection and recognition.
This is the link:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCV 3.0 there is an extra module for text detection and recognition.
This is the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html).
Text detection is mainly based on Extremal Regions and Maximally Stable Extremal Regions.
The recognition part is done by integrating with Tesseract or a letter classifier trained for scene text.
You might tune the parameters of the algorithm, especially the minimum and maximum size of a blob for your case.
Example code:
[link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/end_to_end_recognition.cpp)